# Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset. in spark structured streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying example of spark structured streaming given on the spark website but it is throwing error

**1.  Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.**

**2.  not enough arguments for method as: (implicit evidence$2: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[data])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[data].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$2.
    val ds: Dataset[data] = df.as[data]**

Here is my code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
object final_stream {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .appName("kafka-consumer")
          .master("local[*]")
          .getOrCreate()
        import spark.implicits._

        spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

    case class data(name: String, id: String)

    val df = spark
          .readStream
          .format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "172.21.0.187:9093")
          .option("subscribe", "test")
          .load()
    println(df.isStreaming)

    val ds: Dataset[data] = df.as[data]
    val value = ds.select("name").where("id > 10")




    value.writeStream
          .outputMode("append")
          .format("console")
          .start()
          .awaitTermination()

  }
}
```

any help on how to make this work.?
I want final output like this
i want output like this

```
+-----+--------+
| name|    id
+-----+--------+
|Jacek|     1
+-----+--------+
```

Comment: can you move the case class out of final_stream object and run ?

Comment: If i move case class outside the object it is showing error "Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`name`' given input columns: [topic, timestamp, value, key, offset, timestampType, partition];"

Comment: your data contains [topic, timestamp, value, key, offset, timestampType, partition] but your case class contains only name and id

Comment: how should i solve this error ?

Comment: I just want to display the json string from kafka to spark console through structured streaming

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that you are dealing with `Array[Byte]` as coming from Kafka and there are no fields to match `data` case class.

```
scala> println(schema.treeString)
root
 |-- key: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)
```

Change the line `df.as[data]` to the following:

```
df.
  select($"value" cast "string").
  map(value => ...parse the value to get name and id here...).
  as[data]
```

I strongly recommend using `select` and `functions` object to deal with the incoming data.

Comment: can you please give example of how to parse name and id

Comment: Sure, but that depends on how you send the string with name and id over the wire. How do you publish to a Kafka topic?

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to mismatch of number of column in dataframe and your case class.

You have `[topic, timestamp, value, key, offset, timestampType, partition]`  columns in dataframe

Whereas your case class is only with two columns

```
case class data(name: String, id: String)
```

You can display the content of dataframe as

```
val display = df.writeStream.format("console").start()
```

Sleep for some seconds and then

```
display.stop()
```

And also use `option("startingOffsets", "earliest")`  as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45092445/how-to-display-a-streaming-dataframe-as-show-fails-with-analysisexception)

Then create a case class as per your data.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();; when running df.show()

Comment: i want output like this                                                             +-----+--------+
| name|    id
+-----+--------+
|Jacek|     1
+-----+--------+

Comment: Hope this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45092445/how-to-display-a-streaming-dataframe-as-show-fails-with-analysisexception sorry we cant use .show with streaming

Comment: Above solution is also not working can someone help me with complete solution